# Comparing a java-app with a c-app in kilobytes

Tags: java, c, memory, exe, executable-jar

I have made two rather small applications in java- and c-language. The application is a financial calculator (Black & Scholes) where one can calculate the call- and put-price given the parameters assetprice, strikeprice, volatility, time and interest rate.

I somehow expected the apps to be approximately the same size in kilobytes - but I was surprized when I discovered that the c-file is much heavier:

```
 c-program (exefile): 450 KB
 java-program (jar): 11.7 KB
```

That is - when the c-program is almost o.5 MB the jar-file is as little as 11.7 KB.

How could this be explained?

*(the firt image shows the c-app and the last is the java app)*

[image]

Comment: You forgot to add the size of the JVM to your java code. (And the size of the DLLs required for your C code.)

Comment: As other responses all elude to, you're not making a fair comparison. In most programs, there is much more than the binary file size that needs to be taken into account. Not only the runtime needed to make that binary work, not only dynamically linked libraries that are required, but even comparing two binary files that both started as `c` is unfair without qualification because the file can include content not required for execution but rather exists to assist debugging -- making for very different file sizes that do not reflect actual required code sizes.

Comment: For a more meaningful comparison you should try to package both applications in a manner that each can be installed on a target system without any 3rd party software already installed (i.e. a fresh Windows install), then compare the size of both install packages. Notice that for the GTK version you need to supply GTK in your installer and for the Java one you need to supply a JVM in your installer.

Answer (score 2):

Your trying to compare apples and oranges. Java java is an interpreted language compiling bytecode and using libraries available within the jvm. c compiles into machine code and includes static libraries but not dynamic shared libraries acailable by the os.

So, this depends on many factors and the specific project.

C apps also depend on compiler used and settings. Eg gcc will affect size differently than ms visual studio and a debug mode compile will be way larger than a non debug. Also optimizations and obfuscators play a role.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing all the details I would argue that the c-program is self-contained, i.e. you can run it on virtually any Windows machine.

To run Java applications, you need the JVM installed, which brings a lot of functionality (like... the String type, or Math libraries), so these do not need to be included in your deployed jar file.

Answer (score 1):

The c file has incompiled a lot of runtime and other overhead, while java is almost interpreted. See, c is standalone and java needs the rontime